# mean recurrence time

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

$E\left[T_j |X_0=i,X_1=k\right]$
 \left\ space{\begin{matrix}
1+U_{kj} \space\ k\neq j & \\ 1 \space\ k=j
 &\end{matrix}\right.

Does this mean that the number of steps it takes to get back to state T_j is 1 +U_kj?
I'm not entirely sure what this definition means, from sources online it somewhat describes it as this. Could someone give me a bit more insight in to what it actually means? 
thanks 
sorry about the formatting I tried to copy it from a coding website ....

Comment: Maybe someone else recognizes this notation instantly, but I would need more context. What book? What topics just before this?

Comment: it's from my lecture notes I have an exam in a few weeks and would like to be able to understand it.